# My Linq to SQL query paging logic is not executing in the database

Tags: linq-to-sql, paging

How can I make my Linq to SQL query logic execute on the server?

I have a created a Linq query and returned it as an IEnumerable. Subsequent operations on the query such as .Count() or .Take(5) are evaluated on the client in CLR, rather than on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting to IEnumerable will cause the query to be executed - as a result the data is now on the client side.

If you want to execute paging on the server side, you should perform those operations while it is still a late executing IQueryable.

Answer (score 0):

IEnumerable was the problem. Returning the Linq.DataQuery as an IQueryable allows Linq to SQL to add additional operations to the query. Figured this out as I was describing the problem.

Comment: You should add this as a comment to the question and not as as an answer. Beside, it would be nice if you accepted David answer

Comment: Sorry. I'm new here. In fact, I joined just to solve this problem. I would accept David's answer if I could see how.

Comment: OK, figured that out with the checkbox. The answering my own question was a little silly, but I was stuck on this for an hour until I actually wrote down the word "IEnumerable" in the post and went and chased after that.